# Explicit computation of spectrum of Hodge-Laplacian on forms

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

While I know of some explicit examples (sphere, flat torus) for the spectrum of the Hodge-Laplacian on 0-forms (i.e. the Laplace-Beltrami operator on functions), I haven't found anything for "actual forms", i.e. of degree one or higher.
Does anyone know whether such explicit calculations are available in some book or article?